# How to iterate through a fixed number of files until the last file of the folder?

Tags: python, file, loops

I have a large number of text files (over 2000) within a folder that I need to iterate. This is what I have managed doing at the moment:

```
import os
filepath='E:\Data'
save_path='E:\Results'

for file in os.listdir(filepath):
   if file.endswith('.txt'):
     with open(os.path.join(filepath,file),'r') as myfile:
          for eachline in myfile:
              MainID=eachline[:6]
                  if MainID=='AKJ':
                     for field in eachline.split():
                          MainID=field.split(',')[1]
                          Origin=field.split(',')[9]
                          Price=field.split(',')[13]
                          fo1=open(os.path.join(save_path,file),'a')
                          fo1.write('%s,%s,%s\n' %(MainID,Origin,Price))
                          fo1.close()
```

However, I need my process to be executed for the first 100 files, then for the following 100 files, etc., until the end of the folder, instead of iterating through all the files until the end at once as with the code above. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to perform some process to 100 files at a time, or one process to 100 files sequentially, and then a different process to the next 100 and so on?  Or rather, what is the significance of the 100 files

Comment: Also, you should either prepend your ```filepath``` string with ```r``` to avoid evaluating the ```\``` as a literal (`filepath = r'E:\Data'`) OR use a double ```\``` so (`filepath = 'E:\\Data'`) OR depending on your platform you can use a `/` instead (`filepath = 'E:/Data'`)

Comment: It is one process to 100 files sequentially. I process 100 files, I obtain an output and then I need to process the following 100 files to obtain the second output, etc., until the end of the folder.

Comment: Is the second group based on the output of the first group? Or the larger question here, is there anything wrong with doing them all in one go?

Comment: ok, I am going to copy the rest of my code, it might be easier to understand what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
files = [file for file in os.listdir(filepath) if file.endswith('.txt')]
batchsize = 100
index = 0
remaining = len(files)
while remaining > 0:
    batch = min(remaining, batchsize)
    print('NEW BATCH')
    for file in files[index:index+batch]:
        with open(os.path.join(filepath, file), 'r') as myfile:
            print(' ', file)

    index += batch
    remaining -= batch
```

Answer (score 0):

```
complete_file_paths = [os.path.join(filepath,file) for file in os.listdir(filepath)]
chunks_of_100 = (complete_file_paths[i:i+100] for i in range(0,len(complete_file_paths),100))

for chunk in chunks_of_100:
      print chunk
```

Comment: Hi Joran, I have been trying your code but I only get the last file of my folder processed. I do not know why...